# TFS Gated checkin - prevent build being triggered for javascript file?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, gated-checkin

I am using TFS Gated checkins. I have noticed that every time a javascript file is checked-in, it also triggers the build and it wastes a lot of time.

How can I prevent a build being triggered if a javascript file (or other similar file types) is checked in?

Answer (score 5):

You have two choices:

1. Cloak the folder containing your JS file. If possible, set the Workspace (Source Settings in the Build Definition) to Cloak the path to the file(s) you don't want to trigger a build. This is not possible for a particular file extension though, just paths.
2. When you check in a JS file, add `***NO_CI***` to the end of the check in comment. This prevents a build from triggering.

Or a third choice (not a real option, but I'll put it here just for completeness): If you have permissions on the build to override the gated build, you can just tick the box and bypass the gated build.

Comment: +1 Good info on `***NO_CI***`, was never aware of this ugly hack :)

Comment: @ppejovic This is what TFS uses when checking in the Shelveset of a gated build to prevent it triggering a second build :)